# How are these symbols from Bayesian statistics achieved?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

There's a discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631015/whats-the-mathematical-symbol-to-say-it-doesnt-depend-on) of two symbols approximating `$\coprod$`, `$\prod$`, though these ones are slightly different. They are only presented as part of this image, after the first *X* on each line:

[image]

What is the correct LaTeX for each symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the symbols:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\depkern}{\mspace{-9mu}}
\newcommand{\independent}{\mathrel{\bot\depkern\bot}}
\newcommand{\dependent}{\mathrel{\top\depkern\top}}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{X} \independent \mathcal{Y} \mid \mathcal{Z}$

$\mathcal{X} \dependent \mathcal{Y} \mid \mathcal{Z}$

\end{document}
```

Adjust the figure in `\depkern` at will.

[image]